# Empty or not required struct fields

Tags: go, mgo

I have two structs that represent models that will be inserted into a mongodb database. One struct (Investment) has the other struct (Group) as one of its fields.

```
type Group struct {
    Base
    Name string `json:"name" bson"name"`
}

type Investment struct {
    Base
    Symbol string `json:"symbol" bson:"symbol" binding:"required"`
    Group  Group  `json:"group" bson:"group"`
    Fields bson.M `json:"fields" bson:"fields"`
}
```

The problem I'm having is that in the Investment model, Group is not required. If there is no group, I think its better for it to not be inserted in the db. Whats the best way to handle a db model such as this in Go?

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but you may want to investigate `json.Marshaler` http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler it lets you define custom Marshaling behavior for json, which should (with some effort) allow you to not write a given field based on some logic.

Comment: Struct tags: `json: "omitempty"` should do the trick, from memory.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**tl;dr**: Use `,omitempty`, and if you need to worry about the difference between a [zero value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) and null/not specified, [do what the GitHub API does and use a pointer](https://willnorris.com/2014/05/go-rest-apis-and-pointers).

---

Both `json` and `bson` support the `,omitempty` tag. For json, "empty values are false, 0, **any nil pointer** or interface value, and any array, slice, map, **or string** of length zero" ([json docs](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/)). For bson, `,omitempty` means "Only include the field if it's not set to the zero value for the type or to empty slices or maps", and [zero values](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) include empty strings and nil pointers ([bson docs](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson)).

So if you really need a Group struct, you can put a `*Group` in instead, and it won't be stored when the pointer is nil. If `Investment` only needs to hold the group's *name*, it's even simpler: `""` as group name keeps a group key from being stored.

`bson` defaults to using the lowercased field name already so you can omit that from the struct tag when they match. `json` will default to the Capitalized name, so specify the lowercase name in a tag if you need lowercase.

So, best case, maybe you can just use:

```
type Investment struct {
    Base
    Symbol string `json:"symbol" binding:"required"`
    Group string  `json:"group,omitempty" bson:",omitempty"`
    Fields bson.M `json:"fields"`
}
```

If you ever run into fields where the zero value for the type ("", 0, false, etc.) is distinct from "not specified", you can [do what the GitHub API does and put pointers in your structures](https://willnorris.com/2014/05/go-rest-apis-and-pointers)--essentially an extension of the `*Group` trick.

Comment: Not a Mongo user so correct me if it's wrong. Had read GitHub's post about pointers for omittable fields and the comment suggesting `,omitempty`, and dug up the relevant docs, and looks like it'll work.

Comment: You don't need to specify the lowercase name in a tag for JSON fields. As per the docs: ```To unmarshal JSON into a struct, Unmarshal matches incoming object keys to the keys used by Marshal (either the struct field name or its tag), preferring an exact match but also accepting a case-insensitive match.```

Comment: If you're only decoding you don't have to worry about case, but if you want to Marshal/Encode and have lowercase names appear in the JSON, you have to use the struct tags to ask for it.

Answer (score 7):

**Avoid strut fields to marshal if they are empty** -

A struct field may be primitive type(string, int, bool etc) or even an another struct type.

So sometimes we don't want a struct's field to
go in json data(may to database insertion or in external api call) if they are empty

**Example**:

> ```
> type Investment struct {
>     Base
>     Symbol string `json:"symbol" bson:"symbol" binding:"required"`
>     Group  Group  `json:"group" bson:"group"`
>     Fields bson.M `json:"fields" bson:"fields"`
> }
> ```

If we want that **Symbol** and **Group** might contain empty values(0, false, nil pointer, zero size interface/struct) then we can avoid them in json marshaling like below.

> ```
> type Investment struct {
>     Base
>     Symbol string `json:"symbol,omitempty" bson:"symbol,omitempty" binding:"required"`
>     Group  *Group  `json:"group,omitempty" bson:"group,omitempty"`
>     Fields bson.M `json:"fields" bson:"fields"`
> }
> ```

Her "**Group**" field is pointer to **Group** struct and whenever it will point to nil pointer it will be omitted from json marshaling.

And obviously we would be filling values in Group field like below.

```
// declared investment variable of type Investment struct

 investment.Group = &groupData
```