# Strict JSON parsing in Go

Tags: json, go

The `encoding/json` exposes a forgiving parser. Every not present property is simply set to its default value. Is there a better way to make a field required than using bulky `switch` statments and check every field for its default value? Another problem is that not all default types are `nil`. Is there another way to distinguish between than a not set field and e.g. 0 other than using pointers to be able to check against `nil`?

Comment: Maybe we can see the struct you are using to unmarshal(?) json?

Comment: Unmarshal to `map[string]interface{}` and bind the struct manually would solve both problem.

Comment: @vahdet Sorry, but I can't understand why that would help to solve the problems.

Comment: @leafbebop Thanks, but that would but I would end up with even more boilerplate code.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `omitempty`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216510/empty-or-not-required-struct-fields-in-golang

Comment: @JackGore No, is the question not clear?

Answer (score 0):

You may look at what there is available to implement
so-called "[JSON schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSON_Schema) validation".

You may start with [this search](https://godoc.org/?q=json+schema)
which yields [`github.com/juju/gojsonschema`](https://godoc.org/github.com/juju/gojsonschema) among others;
while I have no idea about its quality, it's used as part of
Ubuntu's Juju cloud orchestration solution so I'd expect it
to be battle tested. Still, caveat emptor.